# Example of FilterCriteriaBuilder usage

Tags: google-apps-script

Can someone provide example of class FilterCriteriaBuilder usage to set a filter by condition (not by value)? I could not find any example at all when I searched. I have a working code for setting filter by value. I would like to set filter by say based on date value.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Here is a sample usage code that I built after trial and error. This builds filter to show all rows whose number is greater than 1000. Other filters can be used accordingly.

```
var dataSheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet().getSheetByName("Data");
var newCriteria = SpreadsheetApp.newFilterCriteria()
    .whenNumberGreaterThan(1000)
    .build();  
dataSheet.getFilter().setColumnFilterCriteria(5, newCriteria);
```